# uiview Transition problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have a UIview holding two other UIviews. that two subviews having 15 buttons and images. i have to translate the parent view. but the translation is not smooth in 3g phone. im using UIviewanimation and CGAffineTransformTranslate for translating the view. please help me for making it more smoother.

Answer (score 1):

This is a though question to answer in a general way. I have had views that scrolled smoothly suddenly animating jerkily after just a small change. In short, you need to make sure to have as few subviews as possible and have as few non-opaque views as possible (pngs with alpha values translates to non-opaque UIImageViews).

If all else fails, you can render the whole view into an image, switch out the view for the image just before scrolling, and then re-insert the view again after the animation. That way, you are only moving one big and (hopefully) opaque view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many images make sure they are small-sized, otherwise theyd take up too much memory and there would be nothing to do. To my experience 4-5 large images(740-480) were too much for the phone to handle.